# Concatenating loop index with field name to dynamically create the JavaScrip variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, frontend

Below is the code to populate hidden fields in my form based on the number of items present in an multi choice field. I find it difficult to create gift_1, gift_2, which is where I need your help. Thanks

```
    if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++) {
          jQuery("input[name=gift_1]").val(selectedValues[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want something like `jQuery(\`input[name='gift_${i}']\`)`? Starting from 0 or from 1?

Comment: Yes, but that should start with 1 not 0 that i holds.

Comment: @CodeForGood Add one.

Comment: This entire code (with corrected semantics) can be replaced by ``selectedValues.forEach((val, index) => document.querySelector(`input[name='gift_${index + 1}']`).value = val);``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concatenate using `"input[name=gift_" + (i+1) + "]"`

or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
jQuery(`input[name=gift_${i+1}]`)
```

---

```
if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++) {
      jQuery(`input[name=gift_${i+1}]`).val(selectedValues[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this give gift_1 or gift_0 in the first iteration? thanks

Comment: @CodeForGood as we are using `i+1` it will give `gift_1`

Comment: @CodeForGood If you start with `var i = 0;`, what is `i + 1`?

Comment: I want to get gift_1 in the first iteration and gift_2 in the second iteration as long the as the array has the elements

Comment: @CodeForGood Using logic, what do you believe it does?

Comment: @CodeForGood Do you know how for loop works? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar Of course yes I do, issue I had was just concatenating, as you corrected in the latest version of your answer. thanks